# Create a race in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm very new to python 3. As an assignment, I am supposed to make a race in python basic Syntax and **without** importing any other additional function, where 3 mice are racing with different odds of winning.

```
from random import randint
import time


def race():
    z = '----{,_,">'  # The mouse.
    j = ' '
    print('\t'*13, '|')  # The finish line. Very sophisticated.
    while len(z) < 50:
        time.sleep(1)
        #or k in range(3):
        x = randint(1, 6)
        j = ' ' * x
        z = j + z
        print("\r" + str(z), end="")  # For clearing printed text. I prefer not to import os.
```

As you might see, I've managed to make one; Two to go. But I've scratching my head for three hours on how to do it, that is how to make them go simultaneously ... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As you've discovered, most consoles will interpret "\r" to mean "move the text insertion cursor back to the beginning of the current line". Unfortunately, there is no equivalent character for "move the text insertion cursor up one line". So if you're planning on displaying your race in a box three rows high, you won't be able to do so with your current text-clearing strategy. Perhaps you could instead create the illusion of text clearing by printing a hundred newlines or so. If this seems janky to you, that's because it is. The console isn't really suited for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, unfortunately the `"\r"` character only erases the current line, but it does not erase the others, making it impossible to create the program with this strategy. The only way to do this is to clear the console using multiple `print("\n")`. See this example:

```
from random import randint
import time


def clear():
    print("\n"*80)

def race(mice = 2):

    mice = ['----{,_,">' for i in range(mice)]
    finished = [False,]

    while not all(finished):

        time.sleep(1)
        clear()

        print('\t' * 13, '|')  # The finish line. Very sophisticated.

        for i in range(len(mice)):

            x = randint(1, 6)
            spaces = ' ' * x
            mice[i] = spaces + mice[i]
            print(mice[i])

        finished = map(lambda mouse: False if len(mouse) < 50 else True, mice)

race(3)
```

Answer (score -1):

- Make a function that takes a string (mouse) as an argument; adds a random number of spaces to it and returns the new string.
- Make three mice.
- For each mouse call the function and assign the result to that mouse.
- repeat until one mouse wins - (string is a certain length).